# is it possible to create a public method that generates an unknown number of private instance variables in C#?

Tags: c#

Basically I am trying to implement my own array class, and I was wondering if creating a public method that generates an unknown number of private instance variables was the way to go? Something like:

```
public class myArray {
    public myArray(int length) {
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int component+i;
        }
    }
    int component(int indexOfComponent) {
        return component+indexOfComponent; 
    }
}
```

I know the the line of code inside that for loop makes no sense. But I just thought I would illustrate what I was talking about. What would result from creating an object from the myArray class with 3 as the constructor parameter would be:

```
public class myArray {
    private int component1;
    private int component2;
    private int component3;

    public myArray(int length) {
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int component+i;
        }
    int component(int indexOfComponent) {
            return component+indexOfComponent; 
        }
    }
}
```

And I know those variables would only exist inside the for loop, but that is the best way I can exemplify what I am trying to do. Is this even the way to go if I am trying to implement my own array class?
Also; there's one more thing about this that I think may deserve a separate question but it's the whole problem with naming variables dynamically with a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically I am trying to implement my own array class

I'd urge you not to do that.

> I was wondering if creating a public method that generates an unknown number of private instance variables was the way to go

No. The variables need to known at *compile-time*.

The "way to go" is to use an array or another existing collection type.

Fundamentally you *can't* implement arrays directly in C#. Arrays and strings are the only objects where the size of an instance varies from object to object. For everything else, the layout is the same for every object.

(As mentioned in comments, you could dynamically create a new type for each instance using `Reflection.Emit` or something similar, but you really *really* don't want to do that.)

Comment: On generating an unknown number of private instance variables, you might be able to do it with Reflection.Emit, but it really is a baaaaad idea!

Comment: @flipchart: Yes, I wondered about mentioning that. Will do so now.

Comment: Okay, but in general can I create new variables after compilation?

Comment: @user2142733: No. As I stated in my answer: "The variables need to be known at compile-time." What are you *really* trying to do where you think this would be a good idea?

Comment: I actually got an assignment where I should implement my own array class.. I just though that might be the way to do it.

Comment: @user2142733: Either the assignment is crazy, or it's not actually asking you to do what you think it's asking...

Comment: It says, very clearly, for me to implement my own array class and use it to implement my own string class. My professor said he would show us how on friday.. So maybe I will just wait.

Comment: @user2142733: Well, you can implement "a class with an indexer" (using arrays under the hood or even just a linked list). Perhaps that's what's intended. It doesn't sound like a very useful assignment.